# Using user controls having his name on a string

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a problem, the functionality I'm looking for exactly is:

I have a grid and datagrid, according to the line to select the datagrid there will be to introduce a user control or other user controls are different pictures I've made polylinesegments, bezier cuadratic ... to introduce the call will name, which build on a string, but I have no way to call it correctly.

This is what I do and it works by putting the full name:

```
d48.Children.Add(new tratsPintados.end148());
```

But put the string, tells me not find the path in the project, what I want is to find the path inside the string.

```
d48.Children.Add(new thestring());
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ummmm.. please review your question.. I cant understand what you're  asking

Comment: Ok. I want to know is like putting a user control inside a grid, referring to its path with a string, not its path directly, because the build path by three variables: path = a + b + c

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to instantiate some class based on its name (without real reference), you will need to use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxz4wk15%28VS.85%29.aspx).
Maybe you can do some lookup by name for the class you need, and then use Activator.CreateInstance to call its default constructor.
I hope this is what you want, the question text is quite confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Reflection;

public object GetObjectFromString()
{

string objectName = "WpfApplication1.uc1";

            Type newType = Type.GetType(objectName, true, true);

            object o = Activator.CreateInstance(newType);

// do what you want with the 'o' variable, maybe cast it to the type you want.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Robaticus, @user629964 if this is the answer could you mark it as the answer please.